# How do I get the body of SENT data with Guzzle PHP?

Tags: php, http, guzzle

I am using Guzzle (v6.1.1) in PHP to make a POST request to a server. It works fine. I am adding some logging functions to log what was sent and received and I can't figure out how to get the data that Guzzle sent to the server. I can get the response just fine, but how do I get the **sent** data? (Which would be the JSON string.)

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => $serviceUrlPayments ]);
    try {
       $response = $client->request('POST', 'Charge', [
            'auth' => [$securenetId, $secureKey],
            'json' => [     "amount" => $amount,
                            "paymentVaultToken" => array(
                                    "customerId" => $customerId,
                                    "paymentMethodId" => $token,
                                    "publicKey" => $publicKey
                                    ),
                            "extendedInformation" => array(
                                    "typeOfGoods" => $typeOfGoods,
                                    "userDefinedFields" => $udfs,
                                    "notes" => $Notes
                                    ),
                            'developerApplication'=> $developerApplication 
            ]
    ]);

    } catch (ServerErrorResponseException $e) {
        echo (string) $e->getResponse()->getBody();
    }


    echo $response->getBody(); // THIS CORRECTLY SHOWS THE SERVER RESPONSE
    echo $client->getBody();           // This doesn't work
    echo $client->request->getBody();  // nor does this
```

Any help would be appreciated. I did try to look in Guzzle sourcecode for a function similar to getBody() that would work with the request, but I'm not a PHP expert so I didn't come up with anything helpful. I also searched Google a lot but found only people talking about getting the response back from the server, which I have no trouble with.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can do this work by creating a [Middleware](http://guzzle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handlers-and-middleware.html#middleware).

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\HandlerStack;
use GuzzleHttp\Middleware;
use Psr\Http\Message\RequestInterface;

$stack = HandlerStack::create();
// my middleware
$stack->push(Middleware::mapRequest(function (RequestInterface $request) {
    $contentsRequest = (string) $request->getBody();
    //var_dump($contentsRequest);

    return $request;
}));

$client = new Client([
    'base_uri' => 'http://www.example.com/api/',
    'handler' => $stack
]);

$response = $client->request('POST', 'itemupdate', [
    'auth' => [$username, $password],
    'json' => [
        "key" => "value",
        "key2" => "value",
    ]
]);
```

This, however, is triggered before to receive the response. You may want to do something like this:

```
$stack->push(function (callable $handler) {
    return function (RequestInterface $request, array $options) use ($handler) {
        return $handler($request, $options)->then(
            function ($response) use ($request) {
                // work here
                $contentsRequest = (string) $request->getBody();
                //var_dump($contentsRequest);
                return $response;
            }
        );
    };
});
```

Comment: Both of these causes something to go wrong and I get a 404 from the server.

Comment: I've just tried (guzzle 6.1), and it works for me. Can you post your full code?

Comment: I have edited my question to show the actual code except for variable assignments and such that aren't relevant. I tried what you posted by adding all your middleware code before my code, and adding the `'handler' => $stack` in  the client object creation command.

Comment: maybe the problem is one of the missing middleware. can you try now?

Comment: What do you mean by "missing middleware"? I don't understand. I thought the middleware was the code you posted for me to try?

Comment: by default guzzle use [four middleware](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/HandlerStack.php#L41). See my edit. Create the stack with `HandlerStack::create();`.

Comment: Thanks. To guzzle, this way too complicated for what should be a simple task

Comment: This code CREATES the instance of Guzzle\HttpClient. Is there an alternative way to ADD a middleware to an EXISTING instance of Guzzle\HttpClient, e.g. one received as an argument?

Answer (score 19):

Using Guzzle 6.2.

I've been struggling with this for the last couple days too, while trying to build a method for auditing HTTP interactions with different APIs.  The solution in my case was to simply rewind the request body.

The the request's body is actually implemented as a [stream](http://php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php).  So when the request is sent, Guzzle reads from the stream.  Reading the complete stream moves the stream's internal pointer to the end.  So when you call `getContents()` after the request has been made, the internal pointer is already at the end of the stream and returns nothing.

The solution?  Rewind the pointer to the beginning and read the stream again.

```
<?php
// ...
$body = $request->getBody();
echo $body->getContents(); // -->nothing

// Rewind the stream
$body->rewind();
echo $body->getContents(); // -->The request body :)
```

Comment: Good stuff. Works.

Answer (score 2):

My solution for **Laravel from 5.7**:

MessageFormatter works with variable substitutions, see this: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/blob/master/src/MessageFormatter.php

```
     $stack = HandlerStack::create();
        $stack->push(
            Middleware::log(
                Log::channel('single'),
                new MessageFormatter('Req Body: {request}')
            )
     );

    $client = new Client();
    $response = $client->request(
        'POST',
        'https://url.com/go',
        [
            'headers' => [
                "Content-Type" => "application/json",
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer 123'
            ],
            'json' => $menu,
            'handler' => $stack
        ]
    );
```

Comment: For Laravel 5.3 users: replace `Log::channel('single')` with `Log::getMonolog()`

Answer (score -2):

You can reproduce the data string created by the request by doing

```
$data = array(
    "key" => "value",
    "key2" => "value",
); 

$response = $client->request('POST', 'itemupdate', [
    'auth' => [$username, $password],
    'json' => $data,
]);

// ...

echo json_encode($data);
```

This will output your data as JSON string.

Documentation at http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-encode.php

**EDIT**

Guzzle has a `Request` and a `Response` class (and many other).
`Request` has effectively a `getQuery()` method that returns an object containing your `data` as private, same as all other members.
Also you cannot access it.

This is why I think manually encode it is the easier solution.
If you want know what is done by Guzzle, it also have a `Collection` class that transform data and send it in request.

Comment: Yes, I knew I could do it this way, but hoped there was a built in function in Guzzle that would allow me to get the request, just like I can get the response with `$response->getBody();`

Comment: Ah, yes I tried getQuery() but it didn't work and so if it's private that is why. Thanks for clarifying that for me.